# Visualize Softmax values in CNN prediction

Tags: cnn, visualization

What is the most convenient way to visualize Softmax values after calling the CNN prediction function? Do I have to collect different probability values and feed them to the matplotlib or are there any more convenient ways/libraries to do this?

Below is one [example](https://towardsdatascience.com/recognizing-traffic-signs-with-over-98-accuracy-using-deep-learning-86737aedc2ab) what I mean:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Fastest and easiest would be [seaborn](https://seaborn.pydata.org/examples/index.html). It's built on top of matplotlib and you can plot your stuff with little code. Once you become to hate matplotlib's paradigm or need something fancier, there's [plotly](https://plot.ly/python/getting-started/).

Comment: Keras library doesn't provide any tools for that?

Comment: Unfortunately, `tensorboard` is limited in that way. I've seen people doing plots and just adding them to session as images. There's no barplot afaik.